# Elasticsearch fuzziness ratio rounding

Tags: elasticsearch

When searching a string with a match query, if `fuzziness` is given as a fraction, the number of errors tolerated will be based on the input tokens' length, according to the following formula: `length(term) * (1.0 - fuzziness)` (see [Elasticsearch documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_string_fields))

**My question is, when the computed value is non-integer, will it be rounded up or down?**

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation, it seems like it's always **rounded down**.

Reading through the output of `explain`, while running a query to match `portobellos` gave me some insights.

- If input query is `portobelloX`, similarity value is 0.9090909 (I guess it's from 1 - 1/11)
- When input is `portobellXX`, similarity score is 0.8181818 (again, 1 - 2/11)

If I set fuzziness is 0.85, the running the second query will not return result, perhaps because similarity score is lower than 0.85.